# QHD display in 1080p

Tags: display, windows-8.1, laptop-display

I just got a 15" laptop with a QHD display (3200x1800). The scaling on windows 8.1 is a complete disaster and strains my eyes to the max.

Is it possible to set the display to 1080p without it becoming fuzzy? Something like cleartype?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that will be possible on a native display.

Possible Alternatives:

For overall scaling: Right click on desktop -> Select screen resolution -> click on make text and other items larger or smaller and then try moving the bar and see if it solves the problem.

For app based scaling: Right click on the app executable -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Check "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".

Buy an external monitor with a 1080p native resolution and mirror or extend the screen.

Hope my answer helped.

Comment: I'm already using the scaling functionality in 8.1. It's still not optimal. Thinking about just dealing with it

Comment: I understand, I own a surface pro with 1080p in a 10 inch screen. Everything is so freakishly small to code on. Another recommendation is to buy gunnar gaming glasses, they reduce eye strain and provide a litle magnification, just enough to read properly, and it increases contrast so you can focus on things better. Give it a try. :)

Answer (score 3):

No. You can, however, set it to 1600x900. This means one “Windows pixel” will occupy exactly four (2×2) “real pixels” on your display. Unless, of course, some crappy scaling algorithm were to thwart this endeavor.

Comment: We do this at work... Seems ok

Comment: yeah this looks as bad as 1080p (i had scaling turned off). I should have informed myself better about this laptop

Comment: Sometimes, you can’t turn off the scaling the display itself does. In most cases, it’s an “intelligent” algorithm instead of simple pixel doubling.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is DPI Scaling. Here is a good blog post about it:

http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements.aspx